# Display "Item already exists" under the specific field in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Is there a way to display a message under the relevant field in asp.net mvc once the checked occurred during a post?

If I set my Name property in my DTO class to [Required] and I leave it blank, it will display an error message below the relevant field to let me know that this field is required.

I'd like to do the same when I check if the name already exists but I check it when I post the form.

Can this be achieved or do I just need to display it in the summary?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out.

After checking if a record already exists, you just set the ModelError to the same name as the property and return your DTO object back to the view.

```
ModelState.AddModelError(nameof(dtoProductCreate.Name), 
$"This {nameof(dtoProductCreate.Name)} already exists.");

return View(dtoProductCreate);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You could look into using `IValidatableObject` for custom validation that will be invoked by the model binder.

Comment: @Oliver or you could use a `CustomValidationAttribute`, which will call a custom validation method. This will also give you access to the property's `DisplayAttribute` value, which is what `Html.LabelFor()` uses, so the user sees the field's label and not the name of the underlying property.

Comment: @Thierry making the validation in the model class, if possible, is also better design, as it turns it from a simple DTO to a basic business logic unit, responsible for validating itself.